# How I can add username text to my Spark AR filter?

Tags: javascript, facebook, instagram, dynamic-text, spark-ar-studio

I would like to add the username text in my Spark AR filter.
I created a 2dText object and I would like to change that text into the username of the person that are using the filter. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Filters do not get access to User Name.

You can instead add an Editable Text element and ask your users to enter their names while using the effect

https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/documentation/building-your-scene/2d/editable-text/